# add the OWL Carousel Slider block in the content Unero theme

Tags: magento, slider, block, magento2, owl-carousel

I'm wearing magento 2.2.2 and using Unero theme, I'm developing magento frontend. when I add the OWL Carousel Slider block in the content section it is not visible?

[image: The first step]

[image: the second step]

[image: third step]

[image: console errors on my Browser]

Comment: in the second step I've followed the tutorial at http://themes.magesolution.com/unero/docs/m2/index.html#owl-carousel-builder

Comment: several things need to be check: is there any error in browser console, have you clean the full page cache, browser cache? did you create the owl carousel successful, can you see it in database? is there any error in var/log folder which may related with that one?

Answer (score 0):

check your browser console if you get some error try to fix first. Its seem like jquery conflicts at some point. or if you can post console errors that would be helpful in understanding situation.

Comment: thanks for your answer i've added a step by step image maybe it helps

Comment: Sometimes this error occur due to magento cache, try to flush cache. Login to magento admin, goto system -> cache management. "flush Magento cache", "Flush Cache Storage"

Comment: I have applied your advice but still the same, nothing happened